# Ubuntu server on Raspberry PI 4b - Xserver won't start on reboot

Tags: server, xorg

I followed the [instructions here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#1-overview) to install the latest Ubuntu LTS server version (Jammy 22.04.3 LTS) on my Rasp Pi 4B, then used:

```
sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop
```

To install a GUI. However, when I reboot the PI the GUI doesn't start. I checked that it's set to start a GUI using:

```
@raspberry-pihole:~$ systemctl get-default
graphical.target
```

And if I open a console I can start an xserver using "startx".

Version:

```
@raspberry-pihole:~$ uname -a
Linux raspberry-pihole 5.15.0-1045-raspi #48-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Tue Jan 16 13:24:44 UTC 2024 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

I want the PI to run MagicMirror2, and I've got that all installed and configured and it starts automatically after I run 'startx'. However, of course, it doesn't not work on reboot.

EDIT:

```
@raspberry-pihole:~$ systemctl status display-manager.service
● sddm.service - Simple Desktop Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sddm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-02-02 15:17:27 NZDT; 1h 0min ago
       Docs: man:sddm(1)
             man:sddm.conf(5)
   Main PID: 2504 (sddm)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 2077)
     Memory: 10.2M
        CPU: 77ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/sddm.service
             └─2504 /usr/bin/sddm

Feb 02 15:17:27 raspberry-pihole systemd[1]: Starting Simple Desktop Display Manager...
Feb 02 15:17:27 raspberry-pihole systemd[1]: Started Simple Desktop Display Manager.
Feb 02 15:17:27 raspberry-pihole sddm[2504]: Initializing...
Feb 02 15:17:27 raspberry-pihole sddm[2504]: Starting...
Feb 02 15:17:27 raspberry-pihole sddm[2504]: Logind interface found
@raspberry-pihole:~$
```

Comment: Have you checked the display manager service status (`systemctl status display-manager.service`)?

Comment: Updated question. Run the above command, says "active: running". Could that be because I ran "startx" manually though?

Comment: No, "startx" shouldn't be a problem that would affect the status of display-manager.service on usual Ubuntu.

Comment: It's a long time since I installed Ubuntu on a RasPi, but wasn't there a setting in `raspi-settings` that caused the RasPi to boot to a command prompt, rather than a graphic environment?

Comment: Does `journalctl -b -u sddm` show further output after `Logind interface found`? In a regular sddm greeter scenario you'd expect lines like `Adding new display on vt 1 ...`, `Display server starting...`, `Running: /usr/bin/X ...` and so on